# Register event listener in a Symfony app

Tags: php, symfony, events, doctrine, sonata-admin

I am trying to get a very basic event listener to run on prePersist in a Sonata application that uses Symfony 2.x.

Here is my listener logic:

```
class GroupAdditionCheckerService implements GroupAdditionCheckerInterface
{
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        die('I am dying');
    }
}
```

... and here is the entry in my services.yml file, per the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html):

```
  app.listener_group_add:
      class: MyOrganization\AppBundle\User\GroupAdditionCheckerService
      tags:
          - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

But when I save an entity, my "I am dying" text does not show up, and the save appears to be successful.

**What do I need to change?**

Comment: Did you clear the cache?  I assume you persisted your new entity.  Which services.yml file did you edit and are you sure it is being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, this isn't an answer to my original question, but for what it's worth: Switching from prePersist to preUpdate seems to have fixed the problem. So my services.yml file now looks like the following:

```
  app.listener_group_add:
      class: MyOrganization\AppBundle\User\GroupAdditionCheckerService
      tags:
          - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

... and my listener looks like this:

```
class GroupAdditionCheckerService implements GroupAdditionCheckerInterface
{
    public function preUpdate(\Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        die('I am dying.');
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you were using an existing entity?  prePersist will only be called on new entities.  Even calling persist on an existing entity will not trigger it.

Comment: Yes, this was indeed an existing entity. I think you found my issue!